# Reading string separated by spaces into vector in C++

Tags: c++, string, file, vector, text-files

Heres what my test.txt looks like:

```
18 19 20
21 22 23
22 23 24
23 24 25
24 25 26
25 26 27
28 29 30
29 30 31
```

I want to read in the integers in test.txt as strings then create a vector of 3 ints.
If that makes sense, so the output is a vector looking like:

```
18 19 20, 21 22 23, 22 23 24, 23 24 25, 24 25 26, 25 26 27, 28 29 30, 29 30 31
```

Heres my code:

```
#include "test.txt"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
struct M
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
};

int main(){
  ifstream file;
  file.open("test.txt");
  string value;
  M XYZ;
  vector<M> Vec;
  if (file){
    while (getline(file, value)){
      XYZ.x = stoi(value);
      if (value == " ")
        XYZ.y = stoi(value);
      if (value == " ")
        XYZ.z = stoi(value);
    }
    Vec.push_back(XYZ);
  }
  else
    cout << "Error openning file." << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < Vec.size(); i++)
    cout << Vec[i] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I think I'm using getline and stoi correctly but could be wrong.
Logic seems correct for the most part.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...so what's the problem? What is your question?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Please tell us what issue you are having with your code. If this is a code improvement question then it is better asked at [CodeReview StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I would replace what's inside your `while` loop with a `std::stringstream ss;`, see http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/95826-stringstream-tutorial/ , then use the `ss` to fill in the structure, like `ss >> XYZ.x >> XYZ.y >> XYZ.z;` In this way, you don't have to care about whitespaces etc.

Comment: I think the problem is that code not working. First why did you include "text.txt" ?? Second you read the input into Vec Vector but you are printing Moves vector? is that code complete?

Comment: Sorry my question is that I don't know why I'm getting this error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoi
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Please search for near-duplicates on StackOverflow: "c++ read file array".

Comment: Whoops I meant to print the Vec Vector, typo @CagkanToptas

Comment: You're calling `stoi(value)` three times on the same string. Calling `stoi` doesn't modify the input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `std::stringstream` should make things less error prone

```
while (getline(file, value))
{
      std::stringstream ss(value); // must #include <sstream>
      ss >> XYZ.x >> XYZ.y >> XYZ.z;
}
```

Your code is not working now because of what @Jonathan Potter commented.

Comment: Thanks. However when I try to print the contents, I get the error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’ cout << Moves[i] << endl;

Comment: That's because `Moves[i]` is a `struct`. Try displaying each element separately, like `cout << Moves[i].x << Moves[i].y << Moves[i].z`, or overload `ostream& operator<<` for your struct.